# How to make a div fall on hover and stay at at the bottom of the page using jquery or css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div box fall when the mouse hovers over it. So far I have done this in css using @keyframes but the box appears back at the top when you stop hovering.

I want the boxes to stay at the bottom of the page, as if they had fell. Is there a way to do this in css or Jquery? Thanks!

Comment: Have you googled JS physics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the animation is not smooth, I think this what you are looking for.

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/tekesteg/full/MyGoJo/) I just created. If you want it to be at the bottom of its wrapper instead of the body, you should give your wrapper div a `position: relative`.

```
div.drop-me {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background: #000;
}
.hovered {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}

<div class="drop-me"></div>

$('div.drop-me').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
});
```

Add this to your head

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! how do i link the Jquery to my html in the <head>?